# How to use Expression.MakeIndex in Linq Expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression

Property indexer array

trying to dynamically generate the following lambda expression:

```
Expression<Func<Program, string>> y = _ => _.x[0];
```

Where x is of type List

Attempting to use Expression.MakeIndex, but it seems to be bouncing an exception:

```
Expression.MakeIndex(parameter, typeof (Program).GetProperty("x"), new[] {Expression.Constant(0)})
```

The exception message:

> Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] get_x()'

How can I make this right?

Comment: "seems to be bouncing an exception". Well it seems you forgot to tell us which one - and what message it contains...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two operations going on here:

1. Get `x` from `parameter`
2. Access item at index 0

You need to create two separate expressions for this:

```
var property = Expression.Property(parameter, typeof (Program).GetProperty("x"));
var itemAtPosition0 = Expression.MakeIndex(property, typeof(List<string>).GetProperty("Item"),
                     new [] { Expression.Constant(0) });
```

`"Item"` refers to the default name of the indexer property. For more information about this name and how to reliably detect the actual name used, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6759445/572644).

Comment: Thank you, the link also answers my other question- if it's always going to be "Item" why create a parameter where you can pass another name in.

Comment: Thank you for the solution - worked perfectly after hours of trying.
However, it didn't work until I re-assigned back as " property = Expression.make.... "
Appreciate if you can update the answer.

Comment: Well yeah, obviously you need to assign the result of `MakeIndex` to a variable to actually use it...

Answer (score 3):

This answer assumes that the `Program` class is defined like this:

```
public class ProgramZ
{
    public List<string> x { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that you are trying to applying the indexing to the `Program.x` property, when it really should be applied to the `List<string>`'s indexer property (which is called `Item`).

In the end, to be able to Invoke the expression you need to wrap it into a lambda.

Here's the code to do that:

```
var expr =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<Program, string>>(
        Expression.MakeIndex(
                Expression.Property(
                    parameter,
                    typeof(Program).GetProperty("x")),
                typeof(List<string>).GetProperty("Item"),
                new[] { Expression.Constant(0) }),
        parameter);
```

And here's how to invoke the expression:

```
var instance = new ProgramZ { x = new List<string> { "a", "b" } };

Console.WriteLine(expr.Compile().Invoke(instance));
```

This code will output `a`, as expected.