# Get a type's indexer as PropertyInfo using literal expression lambda syntax

Tags: .net, expression, expression-trees

I seek a way to get a type's indexer property using lambda syntax.  This question shows you how to get it using reflection:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9716775/701346

I tested that solution and it works, but it's a bit too big and burly for my tastes.  I want to do it like this:

```
Expression<Func<Dictionary<string, string>, string>> index =
    e => e[default(string)];
```

What this gets me is a `MethodInfo` for the indexer's get accessor, but I need to get the indexer as a `PropertyInfo` so that I can pass it into `Expression.MakeIndex`.

What do I gotta do?

Answer (score 0):

Was going to just delete this, but thought I'd keep it around in case it helps.

How dumb of me not to think to use `Expression.Call` instead of `Expression.MakeIndex`.

```
var p_formcollection = Expression.Parameter(typeof(FormCollection), nameof(FormCollection));
//helper method that does the same thing as in my OP
//I also used Dictionary<,> in my OP, but it's really a FormCollection
var indexer = ExpressionHelpers.GetMethodInfo<FormCollection, string>(e => e[default(string)]);
var collectionAccess = Expression.Call(p_formcollection, indexer, Expression.Constant(pi.PropertyInfo.Name));
```